# Meteor set button value to session

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I would like to be able to save a value from a button into a session variable on click. fyi- The button does not submit anywhere.
I hope I am using the terminology correctly, if not please correct me.

Here's what I have:

```
<button class="button button-small button-stable" data-ion-modal="_Modal" value="November-26-2015">'26'</button>

Template.calendar.events({
  'click .button' : function() {
   var value = this.value;
   Session.set( "DateEditing", value);
   var clickedDateValue = Session.get('DateEditing');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Template.calendar.events({
  'click .button' : function(event, template) {
     var value = event.currentTarget.value;
     Session.set("DateEditing", value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Is there any way to do this without jQuery?

Comment: @user3795286 please check out the changes

Comment: Once again you nailed it! Thank you!